# PHPMailer loop sending through gmail fails in the middle

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer to send emails from a Gmail address. I loop through a customer database to send the emails and in my test the total number sent would be about 200. In my test, it sent about 80 without error, and then suddenly failed with the error:
`Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.`

I tried 3 times with the same result, though it doesn't fail at exactly the same point each time. I don't know how the authentication could suddenly fail after succeeding 80 times. Is this some kind of known problem with Gmail? Here's my code:

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'xxxx@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'xxxx';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->setFrom('xxxx@gmail.com', '');
    $SQL="SELECT ID_NO, EMAIL FROM CUSTOMERS";
    $qry = sqlsrv_query($conn, $SQL);
      while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($qry, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)) {
      $mail->ClearAddresses();
      $mail->addAddress($row['EMAIL'], '');
      $mail->Subject = 'xxxx';
      $mail->Body = 'xxxx';
      $mail->send();
      usleep(200000);  // avoid sending too many emails in a very short time
    }
```

Comment: From your code, it looks like you have not set up XOAUTH2 auth in gmail; you'll need to do that. See the PHPMailer docs for examples.

Comment: How does that explain that it fails in the middle after sending a bunch successfully? I am using a Gmail app password.

Comment: Could be a symptom of some rate limiting? Gmail isn't intended as a bulk-mail relay. Maybe turn on PHPMailer's debug mode in case there is more detail anywhere.

Comment: I just ran another test and this time all the emails were sent.  I did turn on debug mode and no errors were reported. So it's apparently not even predictable.  It shouldn't be rate-limiting because Gmail allows 500 emails to be sent per 24 hours. Until recently, my client was using a Windows executable to send through this same Gmail account and there was never a problem. But I don't think I can rely on it any more.